# if(l==complist[0]): ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

```
a,b=0,700
l=random.choice(complist)

h, w, c = l.shape
img[a:h+a, b:w+b] = l
if(l==complist[0]):
    z=myList[0]
if(l==complist[1]):
    z=myList[1]
if(l==complist[2]):
    z=myList[2]
```

Error in `if(l==complist[0]):`

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I got this error. Can anyone help me...

Comment: Please add more details about complist

Comment: If I am correct, you want to compare images. I would suggest to use a metric like structural similarity index measure (SSIM) as it is implemented for example  in skimage.metrics.structural_similarity.

Answer (score 0):

`l==complist[0]` is just another array, whose values are boolean (each value `(l==complist[0])[i]` is equal to `l[i]==complist[0][i]`, so the equality test on two arrays does the equality test on each pair of elements and stores those in a new array, much like addition or multiplication), to check whether all those are `True`, just use `np.ndarray.all`:

```
if (l==complist[0]).all(): # basically if `l` equals `complist[0]`
    ...
```